# How to search multiple patterns in using grep command?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am learning to use grep and I tried to use the following commands to find entries in `/var/log/messages` file, but I get errors:

```
grep "Oct 23 21:22:44" | "80" /var/log/messages
```

I get error for this. Than I tried the following and replaced double quotes with single quotes:

```
grep 'Oct 23 21:22:44' | '80' /var/log/messages
```

This did not work either. Why is it wrong because we can search multiple patterns using pipe!
Is it because Oct 23 21:22:44 and 80 are in different places!

80 and the date are in different orders in the file!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this syntax:

```
grep "Oct 23 21:22:44" | "80" /var/log/messages
```

is equivalent to running `grep` and pass output to a file called `80`.

A way to do What you need is enabling `-E` option (`--extended-regexp`) to be able to use `|` as-is, like this:

```
grep -E "Oct 23 21:22:44|80" /var/log/messages
```

Comment: Thank you reply! This does not give any error, but it only shows a new line. The date and number 80 are in different places in the file! Do you think that is causing problem?

Comment: It works now. I don't know why it did not work before! Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: The `-E` just allows you to use an unescaped pipe in the regular expression, but the character itself must *still* be escaped at the shell level. Any of `grep foo \\\| bar file`, `grep "foo \| bar" file`, `grep -E foo \| bar file`, or `grep -E "foo | bar" file` should work.

Comment: @chepner thanks for the precision. `-E` is still enabling "extended" regexes, so accepting `|` as-is is just a nice side effect I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `-e` option:

```
grep -e 'Oct 23 21:22:44' -e '80' /var/log/messages
```

If search terms doesn't require regular expressions, `-F` option can be used - it is faster as well as avoids need of escaping meta characters. Thanks @mklement0 for pointing it out.

Also, use single quotes unless you need to perform [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution), [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution), etc. Related: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters/131767#131767)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 changes required to be done in your command:

- For multiple search criteria in single GREP command use -E parameter
- Combine all criteria with pipe chars. and *no spaces in between*.

`grep -E "Oct 23 21:22:44|80" /var/log/messages`

Comment: `-E` is only needed to use an unescaped pipe in the regular expression. `grep "Oct 23 21:22:44\|80" ...` would work fine.